# image background issue in cocos2d

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I use random image for background.I want to set background instead of black color as shown in figure.
[image]

In this image promotion box is an obstacle and and white background is an image named backimage.you can see there is a little bit of black color i just want to make backimage on background.

Here is my code:

```
 +(id) scene
{
    CCScene* scene = [CCScene node];

    GameScene *layer1 = [GameScene node];

    CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"admin.png"];
    background.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);

    [layer1 addChild:background z:-1];

    [scene addChild:layer1 z:0];
    return scene;
}
```

Comment: why are you using admin.png as background if your background image is "backimage"

Answer (score 1):

Try with following code for set backGround image:

```
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object.
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    CCSprite *backgroundIMG = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mainBg.jpg"];
    CGSize imageSize = backgroundIMG.contentSize;
    backgroundIMG.scaleX = winSize.width / imageSize.width;
    backgroundIMG.scaleY = winSize.height / imageSize.height;
    backgroundIMG.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    [layer addChild:backgroundIMG z: -1];

    // add layer as a child to scene
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way ,it will working in my project:

```
        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

        CCSprite *Background  = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Background.jpg"];
        Background.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:Background];
```

may it will help.